# How do I validate this email contact form with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Link to website: http://www.leonardpfautsch.com/contact.php

How do I make my contact form validated only using PHP? I want to be able to have error messages directly under the text field that has an error. For each text field, I do not want multiple errors to show up at once. If you submit the form with nothing in the fields, you see that under name and email two errors show up for each. I want the errors to show up only once due to some type of specifications. Right now I think I am on the right track. However, the code below does not have the email being sent. I am very new to PHP. If anybody could help me, I would really appreciate it.

```
<?php

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))){


    $errors = array($name_error_1, $name_error_2, $email_error_1, $email_error_2, $subject_error, $message_error);

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


if ($name === '') {
    $name_error_1 = '<div style="color:red;"> Name is a required field! </div>';
}

if ($email === '') {
    $email_error_1 = '<div style="color:red;"> Email is a required field! </div>';
}

if ($subject === '') {
    $subject_error = '<div style="color:red;"> Subject is a required field! </div>';
}

if ($message === '') {
    $message_error = '<div style="color:red;"> Message is a required field! </div>';
}

if (isset($email) && (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)){
    $email_error_2 = '<div style="color:red;"> The email address must be real! </div>';
}

if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
    $name_error_2 = '<div style="color:red;"> Your name must only contain letters! </div>';
}

    /*Main way that mail works*/
    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        /*Where_mail_goes_to, Subject, Body_text, Who_email_is_from*/
        mail('email_address', $subject, "From " . $name . "\r\r" .  $message, 'From: ' . $email);
        /*Shows up in the URL if the message has been sent*/
        header('Location: contact.php?sent');
        exit();
    }

} //end of main if

?>


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
                    <span class="label">Name</span><br/>
                    <?php if (isset($name_error_1)) { echo $name_error_1; } ?>
                    <?php if (isset($name_error_2)) { echo $name_error_2; } ?>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="name" size="50" maxlength="50" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?> > <br/>
                    <span class="label">Email</span><br/>
                    <?php if (isset($email_error_1)) { echo $email_error_1; } ?>
                    <?php if (isset($email_error_2)) { echo $email_error_2; } ?>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?> > <br/>
                    <span class="label">Subject</span><br/>
                    <?php if (isset($subject_error)) { echo $subject_error; } ?>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="subject" size="50" maxlength="50" <?php if (isset($_POST['subject']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['subject']), '"'; } ?> > <br/>
                    <span class="label">Message</span><br/>
                    <?php if (isset($message_error)) { echo $message_error; } ?>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="textarea" maxlength="500"><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true){ echo $_POST['message'];}?></textarea><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="action"> 
                    </form>
```

Comment: do you need only one error msg to show below the field then you just need to use else if, or you need something else?

Comment: I need that and I also need to get the form to send the email because right now it is not being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of errors for each field and display just the first error added to it.

```
<?php
$email_errors = array();

if ($email == '')
{
    $email_errors[] = 'First error';
}

if (more_email_checks($email) == false)
{
    $email_errors[] = 'Second error';
}
?>

...

<span class="label">Email</span><br />
<?php echo array_shift($email_errors); ?>
```

To know whether to send e-mails or not, you could do something like this:

```
$errors_found = 0;

if (check_email($email) == false)
{
    $email_error = 'Error message';
    $errors_found++;
}

...

if ($errors_found == 0)
{
     mail(...);
}
```

Comment: Okay but then how do I have the email actually be sent from doing this? Right now the email is not being sent. How do I modify my if statement with the mail function in it?

Comment: Depending on your operating system, can you send e-mail from the command line? You can use this for Linux/Mac: http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/

Comment: I was able to send the email before if I did not put in my variables inside of my $errors array. I am using a hosting service which runs on Linux and it worked previously. I know how to send it from the command line if I have too.

Comment: My guess is `empty($errors)` will never be true, because the array is not empty. `empty` won't tell you if all values of the array are empty. Because it is never true, the `mail` function is never reached.

Comment: Right. That is what I was thinking also. I want the email to only send  if there are no errors. So how can I adjust my script to do that?

Comment: Your edits fixed everything. Thank you so much! You are so kind! God bless you and have an excellent rest of July 4th!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `elseif` check

```
<span class="label">Email</span><br/>
<?php if (isset($email_error_1)) 
{ 
echo $email_error_1; 
}
elseif(isset($email_error_2)) {
 echo $email_error_2; 
} ?>
```

Also move this line after the last validation check

```
if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
    $name_error_2 = '<div style="color:red;"> Your name must only contain letters! </div>';

}
$errors = array($name_error_1, $name_error_2, $email_error_1, $email_error_2, $subject_error, $message_error);
```

Comment: Okay I tried this and that solved my problem with the multiple errors showing up multiple times. Now when I fill out all the fields correctly, my email is not being sent. How can I fix my code so that it can be sent?

Comment: have you entered email address instead of `email_address` like test@test.com

Comment: Yes. I did not want to put my email address on here. I have it in my code and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can by this code for name

```
<?
$message = "<div style = 'color :red ' />  ; 
if (isset(name == '' ) {
 echo $message 
}
?>
```

this is  name php vaildation  but yo can  create js

Comment: Can you explain to me what this will do? Will this be able to send my email? Because right now it is not being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Change your email validation to:

```
    <span class="label">Email</span><br/>
<?php if (isset($email_error_1)) 
{ 
echo $email_error_1; 
}else if(isset($email_error_2)) {
 echo $email_error_2; 
} ?>
```

same if else can be applied to all the fields with multiple validation conditions.

and then move your error array just above the email condition check:

```
<?php
$errors = array($name_error_1, $name_error_2, $email_error_1, $email_error_2, $subject_error, $message_error);

//and change your mail function as:


    $to      = 'email_address';
    $headers = $headers .= 'From: $name <$email>';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    ?>
```

Also perform a check on the control, if you have filled the form completely then it should come to the mail function, I mean just check the if condition, in case you have some issue with the condition, try to put an echo inside if statement(which is responsible for sending email), and if that echo statement executes then mail should work.
:)